# How to format SD card that has been formatted as internal storage for Android?

Tags: internal-storage, sd-card, internal-sd, formatting

I have tried `clean all` command in `Diskpart` and it took an hour to be completed but at the end nothing has changed. I think the SD card is locked and when I try to format or re-partition the disk, either it will show a successful result or it will return "Windows was unable to complete the format" error. I have tried to format it in Linux ([this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/196963/impossible-to-format-corrupted-sd-card-formatted-as-internal-storage)) and Android as well but no luck. Is there a way to reuse my SD card as a portable storage?

UPDATE: GParted details when I delete the partition

```
GParted 0.30.0 --enable-libparted-dmraid --enable-online-resize

Libparted 3.2

Delete /dev/mmcblk0p2 (unknown, 59.46 GiB) from /dev/mmcblk0  00:00:08    ( SUCCESS )

calibrate /dev/mmcblk0p2  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )

path: /dev/mmcblk0p2 (partition)
start: 34816
end: 124735454
size: 124700639 (59.46 GiB)
delete partition  00:00:08    ( SUCCESS )
libparted messages    ( INFO )

Input/output error during write on /dev/mmcblk0
========================================

Delete /dev/mmcblk0p1 (unknown, 16.00 MiB) from /dev/mmcblk0  00:00:01    ( SUCCESS )

calibrate /dev/mmcblk0p1  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )

path: /dev/mmcblk0p1 (partition)
start: 2048
end: 34815
size: 32768 (16.00 MiB)
delete partition  00:00:01    ( SUCCESS )
========================================
```

GParted details when I try to format:

```
GParted 0.30.0 --enable-libparted-dmraid --enable-online-resize

Libparted 3.2

Format /dev/mmcblk0p1 as fat16  00:00:01    ( ERROR )

calibrate /dev/mmcblk0p1  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )

path: /dev/mmcblk0p1 (partition)
start: 2048
end: 34815
size: 32768 (16.00 MiB)
clear old file system signatures in /dev/mmcblk0p1  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )

write 512.00 KiB of zeros at byte offset 0  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
write 512.00 KiB of zeros at byte offset 16252928  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
write 4.00 KiB of zeros at byte offset 16711680  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
write 8.00 KiB of zeros at byte offset 16769024  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
flush operating system cache of /dev/mmcblk0  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
set partition type on /dev/mmcblk0p1  00:00:01    ( SUCCESS )

new partition type: fat16
create new fat16 file system  00:00:00    ( ERROR )

mkfs.fat -F16 -v -I '/dev/mmcblk0p1'    ( EXECUTING )

Failed to execute child process “mkfs.fat” (Input/output error)    ( ERROR )
========================================

Format /dev/mmcblk0p2 as fat32
```

Results for zeroing:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=8192

dd: error writing `dev/mmcblk0`: No space left on device

7795969+0 records in
7795968+0 records out
63864569856 bytes (64 GB, 59 CAB) copied, 3824.26 s, 16.7 MB/s
```

Results for [amd64-stdtool](https://github.com/BertoldVdb/sdtool/tree/master/static) status:

```
[+] Found RCA for /dev/mmcblk0: E624.
[+] Card CSD: 400E005A7B590001DED48F700R808006.
[+] Write protection state: Off.
```

Comment: You forgot to describe the actual problem, only that nothing has changed. Usually if you repartition and reformat the card you can simply use it.

Comment: Maybe SDCard is corrupt

Comment: @KirandeepMaan It's not corrupted. Android locks SD cards when they are formatted as internal storage.

Comment: Oh i get it, as i said if window say unable to format then there are two possibilities one is corrupt and other as you mention  locked which doesn't give permission to access its format operation and as alecxs said send some screenshots for reference to solve your matter.

Comment: windows does not allow multiple partitions on sdcard. use linux **gparted** (again, as you stated you already tried)

Comment: 16.00 MiB is a bit small for partition, you should create new partition table and format fat32. the Input/output error may indicate physical dead (wear-out) but can also caused by linux incompatible card reader or wrong drivers

Comment: @alecxs I have not created the 16MB partition and it cannot be changed. it's ridiculous that Android is doing this to SD cards without providing any solution to recovering the SD Card. I tried this on a second SD card and the same problem occurred. So this case is not a hardware problem.

Comment: you can not delete/create partition table?

Comment: No, even after deleting the partitions the same partitions will appear again.

Comment: try `sm set-force-adoptable false` `sm list-disks` `sm partition disk:123,45 public` `sm list-volumes all` from adb shell

Comment: just linked for reference more or less relevant
*problems* [1](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/215493), [2](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/212715), [3](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/211958)
*partitioning* [4](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/189487), [5](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/511194), [6](https://superuser.com/q/1423275)

Comment: @alecxs Your information is outdated. Windows 10 supports multiple partitions on SD-cards and USB sticks since AFAIK Win 10 1903.

Comment: This was possible even before Win10 with a little hack: http://www.etcwiki.org/wiki/Cfadisk_usb_driver

Answer (score 0):

You may go to Settings > Storage. Then go to the more button at the top right corner. There should be an option "Format as portable". Would that work?

Comment: Thx for your answer. however, the question is about I/O errors on (new) MicroSD cards (even after zero-ing whole mmcblk0)

Comment: @alecxs most probably the card is dead. You can try using `mmc-utils` to get low level details e.g. Life Time Estimation and pre-EOL information. But mostly SD cards and USB thumb drives have dumb FTLs. Also many IOCTLs and CMDs don't pass through USB interface and card readers. So the symptoms determine that the card is dead.

Comment: @IrfanLatif it's not my question, but he tried this on a second SD card and the same problem occurred. there are similar unanswered questions - it sounds naiv/stupid but maybe it's true that android lock sd cards in some however way? on the other hand i aggree the best way is to get low level details and base answer on solid facts instead of speculation

Comment: i feel remembered the first day i ever heard about selinux

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is write protection.
I am currently experiencing this problem..

I initially used the sdcard as internal storage so I believe Android will put write protection in the sdcard.

To me the solution is to use Android command line or shell and run Linux command on the sdcard and remove the write protection knowing fully well that only device that encrypte the sdcard can decrypt it.