# Can't use/format SD card formatted as internal storage

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, formatting, nokia-2, nokia

I have a **SanDisk Ultra 16 GB SD Card** and formatted it as internal storage in my **Nokia 2.1** (Android 9 - Not rooted).

I can't use or format the sd card on my phone.

- When I choose to format it as internal storage, I get the following toast:

  `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.storage.VolumeInfo.getId()' on a null object reference.`
- When I choose the other option - formatting as removable media - the format process finished but nothing happens and my SD card is still unknown to my phone.

So I decided to format it with my computer. This is what gparted shows:
[image: gparted]

When I delete these two partitions, the operation completes, but I still have those partitons!

[image]

When I try to delete those partitions and create a new FAT32 partition using GParted, I get the following error:

```
create empty partition  00:00:04    ( SUCCESS )

path: /dev/sdb3 (partition)
start: 2048
end: 31115263
size: 31113216 (14.84 GiB)
libparted messages    ( INFO )

Can't have overlapping partitions.
Partition(s) 3 on /dev/sdb have been written, but we have been unable to inform the kernel of the change, probably because it/they are in use. As a result, the old partition(s) will remain in use. You should reboot now before making further changes.
```

So I tried writing zero to the entire disc, using dd:

```
[dsm@dsm-pc ~]$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb status=progress
[sudo] password for dsm: 
15928488448 bytes (16 GB, 15 GiB) copied, 3894 s, 4.1 MB/s 
dd: writing to '/dev/sdb': No space left on device
31116289+0 records in
31116288+0 records out
15931539456 bytes (16 GB, 15 GiB) copied, 3922.32 s, 4.1 MB/s
```

Nothing happened after that, I still have those partitions!

I don't need my data, is there a way to format this SD Card? I checked many similar questions here and in other websites, but none of them helped.

Comment: it's a unkown problem nobody has solved yet https://android.stackexchange.com/q/221269